# How to validate a text area and throw error while writing?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a text area and I want that if it reaches max length to show a error(not after pressing submit)
Code:

HTML

```
  <textarea maxlength="5000" id="summernote"  rows="4" cols="30"></textarea>
  <p id="message"></p>
```

JS

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var area = document.getElementById("summernote");
    var message = document.getElementById("message");
    var maxLength = 5000;
    var checkLength =()=> {
        if (area.value.length < maxLength) {
            message.innerHTML = "5000 karaktere";
        }
        }
        setInterval(checkLength, 300);
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a `setInterval`, use the `input` event. Also, you are currently checking if the length of the entered string is less than the maxlength when you should be checking if it is equal.

```js
document.querySelector("#summernote").addEventListener("input", function(e){
  if(this.value.length == this.maxLength){
    document.querySelector("#message").textContent = `Max length of ${this.maxLength} characters reached.`;
  }
});
```

```html
<textarea maxlength="10" id="summernote"  rows="4" cols="30"></textarea>
<p id="message"></p>
```

Comment: This works perfectly but I want the message to be deleted if I delete a letter and " this.value.length != this.maxLength " while writing

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine except for one thing wrong, you need to switch the "less than" sign to a "greater than" sign and it will work.

```
if (area.value.length < maxLength) {
```

to

```
if (area.value.length > maxLength) {
```

This works in my browser when I test it. The original code posted displays the message whenever the limit is not reached, but I believe you wanted the error message displayed when the limit is exceeded, so switching the "less than" sign to a "greater than" sign will solve the issue.

Also, one change I suggest making to the code is use your maxLength variable in the error message so you are not writing 5000 twice in the code.

In other words, instead of saying

```
message.innerHTML = "5000 karaktere";
```

You can write

```
message.innerHTML = maxLength + " karaktere";
```

Bruce